# Creating a pandas dataframe produces huge series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using the `SummaryTracker` from `pympler.tracker`. I am trying to figure out why my script is killed though the dataframes in my code should not exceed approx. 0,4gb as I have a matrix
of shape **18125×35232** (if that number is not correct I can change that) and while creating this dataframe pandas Series are present within the RAM which I don't really understand.
Now I am using a tracker to track down which objects make my script stop and this is the result before adding the df:

```
                                   types |   # objects |   total size
======================================== | =========== | ============
             pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           2 |     79.57 MB
          pandas.core.indexes.base.Index |           3 |      1.60 MB
                                    list |       14620 |      1.35 MB
                                     str |       17814 |      1.25 MB
         pandas._libs.index.ObjectEngine |           2 |    640.20 KB
                           numpy.ndarray |          17 |    145.17 KB
                                     set |           3 |    132.66 KB
                                     int |        3316 |     90.70 KB
               pandas.core.series.Series |           1 |     20.15 KB
  pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index |           1 |     20.02 KB
                                 weakref |         101 |      7.89 KB
                                    dict |          22 |      5.85 KB
                                    type |           0 |      1.82 KB
   pandas._libs.internals.BlockPlacement |           4 |    320     B
                                    code |           2 |    288     B
```

After running this code:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('../test_data/test.csv',
                       sep=';', encoding=data_encoding)

data = data.pivot_table(index='index_name',
                                columns='col_name',
                                values='col_2')
```

The result looks like this:

```
                                              types |   # objects |   total size
=================================================== | =========== | ============
                        pandas.core.frame.DataFrame |           3 |      2.92 GB
                          pandas.core.series.Series |         723 |      1.15 GB
                                               list |       29950 |      2.74 MB
                                                str |       33151 |      2.33 MB
                     pandas.core.indexes.base.Index |           3 |      1.60 MB
             pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index |           3 |    966.09 KB
                                      numpy.ndarray |         745 |    706.70 KB
                    pandas._libs.index.ObjectEngine |           3 |    660.23 KB
                                               dict |        1494 |    329.34 KB
                                                int |        7374 |    201.73 KB
                                                set |           3 |    137.16 KB
  pandas.core.internals.managers.SingleBlockManager |         723 |     84.73 KB
                                              tuple |        1346 |     76.71 KB
              pandas._libs.internals.BlockPlacement |         727 |     56.80 KB
            pandas.core.internals.blocks.FloatBlock |         725 |     56.64 KB
```

I get that I will need more space for the dataframes but I do not create series within this code and I am wondering why there is 1.15gb blocked by pandas.series objects. Is this a memory leak and if yes, how can I fix this? If not, can I somehow optimize my code so this does not happen?
Or is this normal behaviour of pandas when creating dataframes? I concat two dataframes with each other after this and it gets even worse to `5.69gb` blocked by `pandas.series`.